# How to fix - If unexpected token - on this exercice

Tags: javascript, arrays

On this example I really don't understand what I am doing wrong. See the code below.

```
<script language = "javascript">

    var month = new Array(12);
    month [0] = "Enero";
    month [1] = "Febrero";
    month [2] = "Marzo;";
    month [3] = "Abril";
    month [4] = "Mayo";
    month [5] = "Junio";
    month [6] = "Julio";
    month [7] = "Agosto";
    month [8] = "Septiembre";
    month [9] = "Octubre";
    month [10] = "Noviembre";
    month [11] = "Diciembre";
    var i = 0;

    do {
        month[i] = parseInt(prompt("Type the number of the 
            month:"));

    }

    if (month[i]>12) {

        document.write("Incorrect month");
    }
    else {  

    document.write ("The month is :" +month+ ".");
    }


</script>
```

Comment: Please format your code so it's easier to comprehend / work with it. See https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.

Comment: What do you expect the `do` block to do?

Comment: Please try to solve any syntax errors, for example by using a linter such as [JSHint](https://jshint.com), and then try to edit your question. As it's currently written, your code does not look like valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guessed you forgot something, so I changed your code. I hope it's ok.

```
<script language = "javascript">

    var month = new Array(12);
    month [0] = "Enero";
    month [1] = "Febrero";
    month [2] = "Marzo;";
    month [3] = "Abril";
    month [4] = "Mayo";
    month [5] = "Junio";
    month [6] = "Julio";
    month [7] = "Agosto";
    month [8] = "Septiembre";
    month [9] = "Octubre";
    month [10] = "Noviembre";
    month [11] = "Diciembre";
    var i = 0;

    do {
    let m = parseInt(prompt("Type the number of the month:")); 

        if (m>12) {
        document.write("Incorrect month.</br>");
        }
        else {  
            document.write ("The month is :" +month[m]+ ".</br>");
        }
    i++;
 } while(i<12)

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Naser Nourani! 

Yes it works, but I want to understand without the "let" command :) (it's bc I'm learning a course and I will learn the let soon).
Let me explain where I am getting in trouble with "my code, yours it's perfect. I don't understand how to get the number from the user, and take that number to check which cell from the Array is, and print it.

Comment: Your welcome.The difference between var and let is just scope . var and let are both used for declaration in javascript but the difference between them is that var is function scoped and let is block scoped.In this case you can use var instead of let,it's  not problem.